# Does the Branch IO will auto renew the SSL certificate for custom Link Domain

Tags: branch.io

My app is using my domain for Link Domain. It saw that the SSL Certificate at `https://app.mydomain.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` has been issued by `ISRG Root X1` and will be expired next month.

Do I need to do somethings to renew it, or will the branch.io auto-renew it for me?

I can not find this issue on the branch.io help pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Branch will automatically renew the SSL.

If you face issue with it not being updated, please raise a support ticket so we can manually renew it.

Comment: I will keep track of the domain and raise a support ticket if needed.
Thanks.